# Stub entire Object in Javascript using Sinon

Tags: javascript, testing, sinon

I am looking for an example for the most trivial [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) use case: mock an entire `Object` / `Array` without methods, static properties only, with another one.

I cannot seem to find how to achieve this using [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/). Pseudo code explanation:

`sinon.mock(originalObj, myObj);
// do tests using originalObj = myObj...
sinon.restore(originalObj);`

Motivation: while this can be achieved easily with a `swap` variable, things become somewhat ugly if you have to mock several objects and the `mock` and `restore` are in different scopes - then you start using a `swap` array residing in a parent scope.

Answer (score 1):

just use `sinon.stub(myObj)` and you will get an object where each property is a stub